# How to edit an int in that "On Click()" in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, i want to be able to edit the number on each button, not in the code, how do i do that?

```
public void ChangeStat()
{
    //assign this function to your Button
    SelectablePart.IndexOfWornItem += 1;
}
```

( i want to change that number 1 on the "on click" thing )

Comment: "Not in the code" is not really describing what you do want. Do you mean like in a configuration file or option menu or something, please be more descriptive about what you *do* want. Or maybe you mean using the inspector? If the method you're assigning to the button in a script that is also attached to the button or if you can make it that way, just do `[SerializeField] buttonVal;` in that script, then use `+= buttonVal;` in the method, and you can set the value of `buttonVal` in the inspector.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is simply making it

```
public void ChangeStat(int value)
{
    SelectablePart.IndexOfWornItem += value;
}
```

reference the method **not via code but via the Inspector** in Unity as a **static** callback and there you can now configure which value shall be passed to the method.

---

Or if your goal is to be able to adjust the passed value on runtime you will need a custom script for that and do e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class IntEvent : UnityEvent<int> { }

[RequireComponent (typeof(Button))]
public class IntButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public IntEvent onClick;

    public int value;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => onClick.Invoke(value));
    }
}
```

and attach this to the same object as the `Button`.

This way you can in that `IntButton.onClick` reference

- **static** callbacks and pass in an int value via the Inspector for each callback individual
- **dynamic** callbacks which will get the value you configured for the entire thing in `IntButton.value`

For more information refer to [Unity Manual - `UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityEvents.html)

Comment: @RodrigoPrimata Glad to help! ;) Please feel free to mark the answer as accepted so others can see that this question has an answer

Comment: Actually, it didnt worked as i wanted 

I'm not very good with english but ill try to describe it

i want to make a clothing system with that

so i want to click on that button and it put the number i want

but this first way it was changing to other clothes i didnt wanted

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the button to call the method in `onClick`. Like this:

```
public Button yourButton;

void Start () {
    Button btn = yourButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    btn.onClick.AddListener(ChangeStat);
}

void ChangeStat(){
    SelectablePart.IndexOfWornItem += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just give reference to the button in the start and then use onClick() and event listner to call the function you told.
Code -

```
void Start ()
{
    Button button = yourButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    button.onClick.AddListener(ChangeStat);
}

public void ChangeStat()
{
    SelectablePart.IndexOfWornItem += 1;
}
```